# file_get_contents(https://xxxxx/js/nav_index.php?lang=zn&index=1): failed to open stream: Connection refused in common/header.php on line

Tags: php, centos, file-get-contents

I have a problem in my website, it has troubled me for some days.

- centos6.7
- domain name ：www.embesttech.cn
- Host Ip: 58.56.53.123(example)
- Virtual machine IP ：192.192.193.11

I want to get menus by:

- `file_get_contents(https://www.embesttech.cn/js/nav_index.php?lang=zn&index=1)`

or

- `file_get_contents(https://58.56.53.123/js/nav_index.php?lang=zn&index=1)`

but no data. The error is:

[image]

When I use:

- `file_get_contents(https://192.192.193.1/js/nav_index.php?lang=zn&index=1)`

or

- `file_get_contents(https://127.0.0.1/js/nav_index.php?lang=zn&index=1)`

It works! Can someone help me?

Comment: If your site needs to make _HTTP_ requests to itself to assemble site parts such as menus, then I’d say, you are doing something wrong already …

Answer (score 0):

telnet 58.56.53.123 80

the error is

trying 58.56.53.123 80...
telnet:connect to address 58.56.53.123:connection refused